# Rails rendering a collection of partials from a presenter method

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, render, presenter

i am busy watching the Rail cast on presenters and would like to refactor one of my presenters to include the page template.

The screencast i was watching is [287-presenters-from-scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch?view=asciicast)

I have initialized a presenter the way he suggested, and created a helper method within the applications helper file..

The view i am trying to build with the presenter is a notification template that is shared with many pages with uploads.

Since you can upload more than one file at a time we may have a few of one type of notice, or a few of each. Data from successful and completed uploads is uploaded, while some uploads that are corrupt may need new import templates, other uploads that are faulty may need fixing. The view for the notifications through the presenter looks like this.

```
- present_upload(host, current_account, current_user, context) do |uploads_presenter|
  .pending_uploads
    = uploads_presenter.display_pending_uploads 

  .faulty_uploads
    = uploads_presenter.display_faulty_uploads

  .corrupt_uploads    
    = uploads_presenter.display_corrupt_uploads

  .completed_uploads
    = uploads_presenter.display_complete_uploads

  .successful_uploads
    = uploads_presenter.display_successful_uploads
```

An example from the presenter

```
class UploadsPresenter 
  attr_reader :host, :user, :account, :context

  def initialize(host, current_account, user, context, template)
    @host = host
    @user = user
    @account = current_account
    @context = context
    @template = template
  end

  def h
    @template
  end

  def display_pending_uploads
    return unless uploads_pending?
    s = []
    pending_uploads.each do |upload|
      s << h.render(partial: 'upload/pending_upload', locals: {upload: upload})
    end
    return s
  end

  def display_complete_uploads
    return unless uploads_complete?
    s = []
    completed_uploads.each do |upload|
      s << h.render(partial: 'upload/complete_upload', locals: {upload: upload})
    end
    return s
  end

  ...
end
```

Only this is being rendered on the page.. its not converting it to readable html but as a array that has been converted to string??

[image: rendered on the page]

i tried calling `return s.join` but that just takes whats inside the array and convert it to string but this renders the same way minus the array symbols.

how would one then render partials from a presenter so that they display as html within the view?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like that you should join array to string and call `html_safe`:

```
return s.join.html_safe
```

or [raw](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw):

```
= raw(uploads_presenter.display_faulty_uploads.join)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! thats exactly what i was looking for. the raw method is pretty awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar issue and found this answer helpful, so wanted to share my findings here. 
I suggest the use of `sanitize` instead of `html_safe` or `raw`. Both `html_safe` and `raw` assume and mark your html to be safe without actually validating them and this behaviour can lead to XSS (Cross Site Scripting) vulnerabilities.

More specific details of `sanitize` can be found [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize).

Just this should solve:

```
= sanitize(uploads_presenter.display_faulty_uploads.join)
```